# Angular 6 - a few components using the same randomised data that's called only once - how to avoid 'undefined'

Tags: global-variables, angular6, angular-services

I'm trying to use the same data in `ngOnInit` of several components, the problem is, the data are random every time I subscribe to it. I can only subscribe one time in the entire run of the app. That means, if I subscribe twice, it won't have any use because each component will have something else.

I want to subscribe once in a service and to create a global variable.
but when you try to use that global variable in all the components (on `ngOnInit`) it is always undefined.

How can I make the components wait for that same thing that can only be called once in the app?

```
export class UsersService {

  public allUsers: Array<Object> = []
  public allUsersUrl: string = 'https://glacial-escarpment-40412.herokuapp.com/users/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.allUsers = data;
        console.log(this.allUsers)
    })
  }

    getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.allUsersUrl);
    }

    getUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.allUsersUrl + id);
    }
}
```

My components:

```
export class FirstComponent {

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.usersService.allUsers) //undefined
    }

export class SecondComponent {

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.usersService.allUsers) //undefined
    }
```

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a synchronism problem. This is your scenario

1- create `first component`
  1.1 - injecting `UsersService`
  1.2 - `UsersService` request for ASYNC data (execution continues)
2- FirstComponent get and print `this.usersService.allUsers` (not still populated because of async request)
3- `this.usersService.allUsers` is still undefined

You need [Subject](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#the-searchterms-rxjs-subject)
Something like this:

UsersService

```
export class UsersService {

  private _allUsersSource = new Subject<Array<Object>>();
  private _allUsers$ = this._allUsersSource.asObservable();

  public allUsersUrl: string = 'https://glacial-escarpment-40412.herokuapp.com/users/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getAllUsers();
  }

    getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.allUsersUrl).subscribe(
              data => this._allUsersSource.next(data)
              );
    }

    get allUsers$(): Observable<Array<Object>> {
        return this._allUsers$;
    }

    // OTHERS
}
```

FirstComponent

```
export class FirstComponent {

  subscription: Subscription;
  allUsers: Array<Object>;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.usersService.allUsers$.subscribe(users => {
                                  this.allUsers = users;
                                  console.log(this.allUsers);
                            });


    }
```

Some thing for `SecondComponent`

Comment: I'm getting two errors: 1) on `getAllUsers()` I get Type Subscription is not assignable to type Observable. 2) Dulicate identifier - `_allUsers$`

Comment: Try now please.